# query doesn't return all data from a column

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I have following code: from the table tenancy_ta_template i have problem to return all text in letterbody column. I have more than 400 characters in the column, but the query only return 255 characters.

```
$query = "select * from tenancy_ta_template where tatemplateid = $tatemplateid";
```

I have try this solution:
In SQL Server Management Studio, select Tools menu, then Options, Query Results, SQL Server, Results To Text. Change the “Maximum number of characters displayed in each column” value from 256 to what ever number you want up to 8192. After you click OK the setting will be saved.

But this solution doesn't work for me. Please help me. thanks.

Comment: would you delete your previous data from log ?

Comment: I don't really understand what your questions means

Comment: Once you done with the settings in SQL Server Mgmt Studio,(256 to 8192), you should try running your query in new session(click NEW QUERY button) not in the existing session i guess. Just give a try.